# POST value from JavaScript to PHP via AJAX without jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I'm trying to send a JavaScript variable to be processed server-side by PHP then echo back the result. My ajax request results in `readyState == 4` and `status == 200` yet PHP keeps echoing back an empty array/value.

I'm pretty sure this comes from my Ajax call sending an empty request but everything I tried didn't work, so maybe I'm going all wrong here.

JS (from `index.html`) :

```
var valueToSend = Math.random(); 

var request = false;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}

function send_ajax() {
    if (request) {
        request.open('POST', 'test.php', true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
            }
        }
        request.send(valueToSend); //this line is probably not sending the value the way I expect it to
    }
}
```

PHP (from `test.php`) :

```
echo $_POST['name']; //simple echo to check if PHP indeed receives valueToSend
```

My last try was to change `request.send(valueToSend);` with `.send(encodeURI('name=' + valueToSend));` but it just made the ajax call redirect the page location to a non-existing one.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is the path to test.php correct wrt the file that this is executing in?

Comment: Just double checked : yes it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things wrong in your code, such as:

- Even through you defined `send_ajax()` function, you didn't call it anywhere in the code.
- With `POST` request you need to send an HTTP header `setRequestHeader()` along with the request, like this:

  ```
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  ```
- `echo $_POST['name'];` in *test.php* page won't work because `name` is *undefined* here. Your `send()` method call should be like this:

  ```
  request.send("name="+valueToSend);
  ```

So the complete JavaScript code would be like this:

```
var valueToSend = Math.random(); 

var request = false;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
}

function send_ajax() {
    if (request) {
        request.open('POST', 'test.php', true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
            }
        }
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send("name="+valueToSend);
    }
}

send_ajax();
```

Comment: Oh my god... I totally forgot about the `setRequestHeader()` method... Works perfeclty fine now. Thank you !